# get a development build from production build in ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have extjs project which is a production build version of an app , now i want to edit the code but as its not a development build (where the whole directory structure exist for model , controllers and views ) so all code is reside into one js file i.e. `app.js`.

so is there a way in ext js where i can get the development build from already exist production build ? i tried to edit my code in WebStrome but my app.js is of more than 86000 lines of code so even my editor is hanging and it makes it nearly impossible to edit the code.

Comment: No, not possible to reverse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not bijective, you loose a lot of information when going to prod : the packages, the name of your files, the indentation, some variable names ...

You can't rebuild it, you have to get the sources from another place.